# MySQL Foreign Key in Table in Another Database?

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to reference (InnoDB) a foreign key in another database in MySQL?

Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible on the same DB server.  Prefix the database name when adding the constraint, e.g. `databasename.tablename.fieldname`.  Watch your user permissions.

I don't consider it bad practice, though it's not something that should be happening very often.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use reference a foreign key in another database in MYSQL.

Thanks.