# How can you create a foreign key to a table in another database with workbench?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, workbench

In MySQL, using MySQL Workbench, how can you create a foreign key relationship to a table which resides in another database? After entering the 'Qualified Table Name', of DatabaseName.TableName.ColumnName, workbench simply acts like I put nothing in the box. Do I need to create these relationships only with manual query in workbench if it is a different database?

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement that is failing.

Comment: @RickJames this post is from 2013, so i'm not even sure which version of workbench that would have been! I have since used modern versions without issue. That is the trouble sometimes with stackoverflow - old questions might not apply anymore but folks can come on and use them as references. Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB engine allows you to define FK(Foreign Key) for tables.(even from other databases)

For this you must mention database name before table and column name. Like so :

```
dbname.tablename.columnname
```

Comment: +1 for stating it can be done. But Please next time read the question. I stated: DatabaseName.TableName.ColumnName in my question, and I was asking about workbench.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. Actually you have to add another schema in your Model which represents your 'different' database.

Then you need to create all your tables (in an EER Diagram) into this new Schema.

Finally, when you'll click on the *Foreign Keys* tab from the original table you'll be able to choose the right table from the different database in *Referenced Table*. For example *different.new_table*

Comment: The only problem with this ( I found ) is when you forward-engineer with drop statements, it'll drop the existing reference schema and replace it with the "recreated" schema. Thank goodness for backups.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is impossible to do what you want. You can not link tables from different databases.

Comment: Based on post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191835/mysql-foreign-key-in-table-in-another-database I know it is possible, just not sure on how to get it done in workbench. Maybe I need to think outside of the GUI and just write the query.